# Spring Security with JWT authorization and Angular 6 login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, angular6

I am trying to connect the front-end on angular with Spring boot using spring security and JWT authorization. The back-end as well as angular service code looks fine to me. I am also getting expected headers with authorization token when checked with postman.

Here's the code snippet:

**The Security Config Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfigurer.class);
    private UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public SecurityConfigurer(UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userPrincipalDetailsService = userPrincipalDetailsService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()).and().csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userRepository))
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userPrincipalDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**Angular Service API**

```
private headers = new HttpHeaders ({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
private options = {headers: this.headers, observe: 'response'};
constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

public login(cred: AuthLoginInfo) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic'});
    console.log(this.baseURL + 'login');
    return this._httpClient
            .post<any>(this.baseURL + 'login', {usernme: 'foo', passowrd: 'foo' })
            .pipe(
              map(data => {
                console.log(data);
              })
            );
  }
```

**Error**

```
{…}
​
error: {…}
​​
error: "Internal Server Error"
​​
message: ""
​​
path: "/login"
​​
status: 500
​​
timestamp: "2020-07-27T09:01:00.643+00:00"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: {…}
​​
lazyInit: function lazyInit()
​​
lazyUpdate: null
​​
normalizedNames: Map(0)
​​
<prototype>: Object { has: has(name), get: get(name), keys: keys()
, … }
​
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8888/login: 500 OK"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 500
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "http://localhost:8888/login"
​
<prototype>: {…}
​​
constructor: function HttpErrorResponse(init)​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Also the post request seems to be working for posting the credentials according to logger on spring boot. But i am getting error in receiving response. I tried debugging it but got no solution.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Error code 500 is internal server error. This would suggest the back-end isn't working as you expected and not taking the input that well. You certain that the headers send from Angular are 100% correct (catch them in Java and copy/paste those in Postman to see if it works).

Comment: How do I catch headers in configure method as HttpSecurity is object passed to it. Also I logged springframework.security in debug mode and found that log for postman request is exact same as the request from angular